# Django create userprofile if does not exist

Tags: django

I use `request.user.get_profile()` in a number of places in my code.  However not all users have a user profile assosiated with their account.  Is there some way I can create a user profile automatically when calling `request.user.get_profile()` if they don't have one without having to change each one of my `request.user.get_profile()` calls.  Maybe using signals or something.

The problem I have is that I use a single sign-in login so if someone logs in on another system and then goes to my site they are logged in but don't get a user profile created (I create a user profile when they log in).

Comment: can you please check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806683/create-row-of-date-while-creating-superuser which i am facing issue,not able to come up

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Usually user profile objects are created right after the user instance is created. This is easily accomplished using signals.

> The problem I have is that I use a single sign-in login so if someone logs in on another system and then goes to my site they are logged in but don't get a user profile created (I create a user profile when they log in).

Apparently using signals at user creation time won't work for you. One way to accomplish what you are trying to do would be to replace calls to `request.user.get_profile()` with a custom function. Say `get_or_create_user_profile(request)`. This function can try to retrieve an user's profile and then create one on the fly if one doesn't exist.

For e.g.:

```
def get_or_create_user_profile(request):
    profile = None
    user = request.user
    try:
        profile = user.get_profile()
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user, ...)
    return profile
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this answer but wasn't keen on changing all instances of request.user.get_profile() in my code. Is there not a signal I could attach to the UserProfile post_get (I don't know if this exists)

Comment: @John: AFAIK there is no built in signal that is sent on `get` (`post_get` as you said). The docs seem to agree http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

Comment: what about doing it through middleware?

Comment: @John: Yes, now that you mention it I guess it would be possible to intercept a request and create an User Profile. Caveat: I have never tried something like it though.

Comment: @ManojGovindan,could you please chech this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806683/create-row-of-date-while-creating-superuser to create the table data in database while creating a user.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution I like to use at this site: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Using a property like this seems cleaner than defining a new method, but I agree it'd be a pain to go through your code base and change `user.get_profile()` references to `user.profile` ones.

Then again, isn't that what your global file search and replace function is for?

Comment: Usually the first user (superuser) won't have its profile created because it was created during `./manage.py startapp`.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it will hit the db to retrieve the profile every time you reference User.profile. e.g. if you do something like: User.profile.field = "derp" then User.profile.save(), it'll reload .profile from the db and lose your changes before saving. Point being it's a bad use of properties. Use a method instead for that functionality imo

Comment: Hmm I don't think this is a bad use of properties. I'll post an improvement though.

Answer (score 2):

Building on bskinner's answer and in response to sqwerty's comment, you might use this:

```
def get_or_create_profile(user):
    """
    Return the UserProfile for the given user, creating one if it does not exist.

    This will also set user.profile to cache the result.
    """
    user.profile, c = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return user.profile

User.profile = property(get_or_create_profile)
```

So this will create a profile if needed, and `User.profile.field = "deep"` then `User.profile.save()` works.

Answer (score 2):

Revised as below. Otherwise, "AttributeError: can't set attribute" will be shown. The guardian assign permission is optional here.

```
def get_or_create_profile(user):
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    assign('change_userprofile', user, profile)
    assign('delete_userprofile', user, profile)
    return profile

User.profile = property(get_or_create_profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickie management command that can be used to create default profiles for any users who are lacking them. With this in place you can run `./manage.py missing_profiles` at any time, or add it to a cron job, etc.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from people.models import Profile

'''
Create default profiles for any User objects that lack them.
'''


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Create default profiles for any User objects that lack them."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        users = User.objects.filter(profile=None)
        for u in users:
            Profile.objects.create(user=u)
            print("Created profile for {u}".format(u=u))
```