# create row of date while creating superuser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

models.py

```
TITLE = (
    ('Classroom', 'Classroom'),
    ('Playground', 'Playground'),
    ('Staff Room','Staff Room'),
)

class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200,default=TITLE)
    parent_location_id = models.CharField('Parent Location', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)

def location_title(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):        
    if instance.is_superuser and not instance.location.is_active:

        instance.location.is_active=True
        instance.location.save()

post_save.connect(location_title, sender=User)
```

I want to insert the default data into database with certain conditions.This should happen while creating superuser via `manage.py createsuperuser` comment.

I don't know it is possible with django,but it is the requirement.I tried with the above code.I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'location'
" while creating superuser.

The sample what i required is given below

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Is any chance is their to implement this.

Comment: what django version is this?

Comment: I am using Django 1.3.7

Comment: then you have to read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: 1. If you're not willing to upgrade to Django 1.5, which includes custom User Models, then you'll have to use a profile, as mentioned by @mariodev.  2. The error you're seeing 'UserProfile is not defined' is likely because you haven't defined the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting.  See again the link above. 3. You should consider creating a custom model manager for your user, which will allow you to modify location while creating a superuser.  See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers), but this may not be available in Django 1.3

Comment: @user2086641: Please see the link above for how to create a Custom Model Manager.  Please ensure that you're doing the work to properly search the documentation before bringing questions here.  Much of what you are looking for is documented with the Django docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function as signal handler:

```
def location_title(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Don't fire up on updates.
    if not created:
        return

    # Only handle new superusers.
    if not instance.is_superuser or not instance.is_active:
        return

    # Create a `Location` entry for new superuser.
    l = Location(user_id=instance.pk)
    l.save()

post_save.connect(location_title, sender=User)
```

Adding choices to model field:

Django CharField has a named argument `choices` that allows you to give the end user a list of possible values, and a proper validation of them in forms. The format of the iterable is as follows `<internal_value>, <display_value>`. Once a field has been passed a `choices` argument, you can access display value connected to it's internal value with `instance.get_<field_name>_display()` method.

The choices iterable could look like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    class Title:
        CLASSROOM = 'classroom'
        PLAYGROUND = 'playground'
        STAFF_ROOM = 'staff_room'

    TITLE_CHOICES = (
        (Title.CLASSROOM, 'Classroom'),
        (Title.PLAYGROUND, 'Playground'),
        (Title.STAFF_ROOM, 'Staff Room'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200,choices=TITLE_CHOICES,default=Title.CLASSROOM)
    parent_location_id = models.CharField('Parent Location', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

The final solution is the following:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    class Title:
        CLASSROOM = 'classroom'
        PLAYGROUND = 'playground'
        STAFF_ROOM = 'staff_room'

    BASE_LOCATION = Title.CLASSROOM

    TITLE_CHOICES = (
        (Title.CLASSROOM, 'Classroom'),
        (Title.PLAYGROUND, 'Playground'),
        (Title.STAFF_ROOM, 'Staff Room'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200,choices=TITLE_CHOICES,default=Title.CLASSROOM)
    parent_location_id = models.CharField('Parent Location', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)


def location_title(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Don't fire up on updates.
    if not created:
        return

    # Only handle new superusers.
    if not instance.is_superuser or not instance.is_active:
        return

    # Create a `Location` entry for new superuser.
    base = Location(user_id=instance.pk, title=Location.BASE_LOCATION)
    base.save()

    for value, _ in Location.TITLE_CHOICES:
        if value == Location.BASE_LOCATION:
            continue

        l = Location(user_id=instance.pk, title=value, parent_location_id=base.pk)
        l.save()

post_save.connect(location_title, sender=User)
```

Comment: The above code is creating  a row in location table.I am trying to include the choices in title field so that i have to create a default data in database.I want the output which is given in sample picture.Can you guide me how to do that.

Comment: If you want to have `choices` in your title field, use a named argument `choices` with value `TITLE`. To set a default value, use an element of the `TITLE` tuple, i.e. TITLE[0][0] to make `Classroom` as the default value for `default` named argument. The choices tuple is a tuple of pairs `<internal_value>, <display_value>` where `internal_value` should be the value used internally - in scripts, db etc. whilst the `display_value` is the value displayed to the front user.

Comment: Just now i checked you comment,it looks like an different approach can you explain me how to do it.

Comment: I tried with the signal handler,sorry to say it is not creating the default and choices value in db.

Comment: What you mean by `default and choices value in db`? Currently, the signal handler creates a single `Location` entry with default value. Do you want to have all 4 `Location` objects created for every single superuser created?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34362/discussion-between-user2086641-and-kroolik)

Comment: The answer which you given is working fine,but after using this i am not able to create the custom choices,previously i can create from application also through add button,a popup will open and if i enter the name like school,a school location will be created but now it is not happening any idea,what could be the problem

Comment: Do you that you want to add additional entry to TITLE_CHOICES via django admin or a view, or add a Location entry to a user via django admin/custom view?

Comment: no,the default choices what we created during the superuser creation can also be added manually,a view and form code is their to create that,after creation of default that one manual add is not working

Answer (score 3):

When you create the user or superuser the model instance is created but it does not have corresponding `location` row. Hence, accessing `instance.location.is_active` gives you the error.

You can update the signal handler to create the `location` instance first and then set appropriate attributes. As below:

```
def location_title(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):     
    #also check for created flag   
    if created and instance.is_superuser:
        location = Location(user=instance)
        location.is_active=True
        location.save()

post_save.connect(location_title, sender=User)
```

If you want to choices for `title` field you can define that in field. Your definition of the `title` field is not correct, change it to

```
title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200, choices=TITLE,  
                         default='Classroom')
```

You are incorrectly using `detfault=TITLE` instead of `choices=TITLE`.

Comment: if created and not instance.is_superuser:-->created a row of data in database.I want to include the choices mentioned in question into title field.How to include it in title field.

Comment: @user2086641, You can set `location.title='Classroom'` as well. Note that `Location` has `OneToOne` relationship with `User` so there can't be multiple location objects (with different title) for one user.

Comment: can it be possible with ForeignKey relationship with user table.

Comment: @user2086641, check for updated answer for using `choices` attribute.

Comment: @user2086641, yes its possible with `ForeignKey()`.

Comment: Do i need to write a separate function to achieve this using ForeignKey()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34348/discussion-between-user2086641-and-rohan)

Comment: The answer what you given is working fine.In my app i have to create 9 title so,the no of lines of code is large,to reduce the line of code is any other alternative way is their to implement the same.

Comment: @user2086641, may be you can shorten it by using forloop!